# CrashRpt not working in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crash-reports, crashrpt

I have created a super simple C++ console application that does a division by zero. I also added CrashRpt to the project and set everything up according to these instructions:

http://crashrpt.sourceforge.net/docs/html/configuring_project.html
(e.g. all debugging symbols are generated also in release build)

When I build and run my application in debug mode everything works fine: the application crashes, CrashRpt pops up and generates a report/dump file.

But when I run in release mode, the application just quits. Nothing pops up, no CrashRpt, no windows message. Nothing.

Comment: What happens if you dereference a NULL pointer instead of doing a  division by 0?

Comment: It shows the same behavior with a null pointer deref: in Debug mode CrashRpt pops up, in Release mode nothing happens (app just quits).

Comment: Did you check what 'additonal include/lib folders' are linked and verified that the correct lib file is added. I just recently linked the library in a Qt program and its working fine.